# table borders disappearing in tcpdf

Tags: tcpdf

I'm setting up tcpdf to generate invoices on the fly for customers, but when I add an image, the borders are disappearing from my table. Here's the code:

```
/*
if ($status == "Paid") {
    $pdf->Image("/wp-content/themes/Feather/images/Paid.jpg", 10, 60, 190, '', '', '', 'T', false, "300", '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
} elseif ($status == "Overdue") {
     $pdf->Image("/wp-content/themes/Feather/images/Overdue.jpg", 10, 60, 190, '', '', '', 'T', false, "300", '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
} elseif ($status == "Cancelled") {
     $pdf->Image("/wp-content/themes/Feather/images/Void.jpg", 10, 60, 190, '', '', '', 'T', false, "300", '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
}
*/
$pdf->SetXY($x=20, $y=30);
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
```

Here's the HTML I'm using:

```
$html = $html . '
<br/><br/><br/>
<table width="600px" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" border="1">
<tr>
    <th width="200px">Product</th>
    <th width="65px">Code</th>
    <th width="65px">Quantity</th>
    <th width="65px">Unit Price</th>
    <th width="65">VAT Rate</th>
    <th width="65">VAT Amount</th>
    <th width="65">Line Total</th>
</tr>';
foreach ($inv_lines as $inv_line) {
$html = $html .
        '<tr>
        <td>' . $inv_line['item_desc'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $inv_line['item_no'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $inv_line['quantity'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $inv_line['unit_price'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $inv_line['vat_rate'] . '</td>
        <td>' . ($inv_line['quantity'] * $inv_line['vat_rate'] * $inv_line['unit_price'] * 0.01) . '</td>
        <td>' . $inv_line['line_total'] . '</td>
    </tr>';
```

The table appears fine with the code as above, but as soon as I uncomment the image bits, the image appears, but the table borders disappear. I've tried adding inline borders to individual cells, but that doesn't make any impact.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First off, make absolutely certain you're always including the end table tag.  TCPDF's html parser can be picky about having opening and closing tags. (I only say this because it's missing in the question.)  It relies on correct markup to function properly.

Now I'm not sure just by looking at your coordinates, but does the table overlap the image?  If it does and you want the borders to be drawn on top of the image, you'll need to call `setPageMark` after you draw the image.  If you don't, the borders will be drawn below the image no matter what order you have the Image and writeHTML calls in.

```
<?php
//In my test PDF I had to do something like this as some of my borders
//were disappearing underneath my test image.
$pdf->Image(...);
$pdf->setPageMark();
$pdf->setXY(...)
$pdf->writeHTML(...);
```

If the border is still not there, that is neither of the above help, you might wanna try setting the draw color after placing the image.  I'm not sure if that would do anything, but it's worth a shot.

Of course, make sure you're on an updated version of TCPDF, depending on your version there may be border rendering fixes.

Comment: Thank you EPB - adding $pdf-setPageMark() fixed it!

Comment: Yep, this was my problem, with all the code I have I forgot to write "</table>" at the end.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, but I have no Images to my knowledge.  Just a table I want to print out, with values in it, that I superimpose on an existing PDF.  I see the table border flash, then when it disappears, the PDF loads, and then the values in the table load, but no table border around them is visible.  I have </table> and I tried putting setPageMark() in various places, but that did not help so far.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how it all works layering one PDF on top of another.  I see you've already posted a question for it, if I find anything out I'll post an answer there.

Comment: Thank you. this fixed my problem. I didn't use $pdf->Image() but load template containing images

Answer (score 4):

Always use `"1"` (double quotes)not single quotes `border='1'` as table border value.